# $f, g$ are analytic at $z_0$. Then $f/g$ is analytic at $z_0$ iff $g(z_0) ≠ 0.$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

How to show

> $f, g$ are analytic at $z_0$. Then $f/g$ is analytic at $z_0$ iff $g(z_0) ≠ 0.$

using $f, g$ are differentiable at $z_0$. Then $f/g$ is differentiable at $z_0$ iff $g(z_0) \neq 0.$

$\Rightarrow$ follows immediately. How to prove $\Leftarrow?$

**I came to know "it is customary in the analytic context to replace removable singularities by their limit." But what if we exclude the custom?**

Comment: What if $f(z)=g(z)=z$, $z_0=0$?

Comment: You might say the opposite implication is false, unless you also assume that $f(z_0)\ne0$. A trivial example: $z_0=0$, $f(z)=g(z)=z$. On the other hand, if $g(z_0)=0$ then you might say that $f/g$ is not even *defined* at $z_0$, and so cannot be differentiable. Which brings us into the land of removable singularities …

Comment: I suppose all you are saying is that the quotient is not even defined if $g(z_0)=0$. On the other hand, it is customary in the analytic context to replace removable singularities by their limit, which explains the previous comments.

Comment: Does the result holds if I exclude the custom?

Comment: The direct implication ($\Rightarrow$) seems useless. If $g(z_0)=0$, then you'll probably study $z_0$ to see if it's a removable singularity of $f/g$, and usually you won't even consider $f/g$ if you don't know the two functions explicitly.

Comment: Just do $\Leftarrow$. You probably know that the product of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic. So it suffices to do this for $f=1$. Take a neighborhood of $z_0$ where $g(z)\neq 0$. Then simply show that $\frac{1}{g}$ is complex differentiable on this neighborhood. Just like you would do it in the real case. The derivative is, of course, $-\frac{g'}{g^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$(f/g)'$=$($f'g-fg'$)/(g^2)$ so if f and g are differentiable then $f/g$ is also differentiable as long as $g\neq0$

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is analytic at $z_0\implies g$ is continuous at $z_0\implies \lim_{z\to z_0}g(z)=g(z_0)\ne 0\implies \exists$ a neighborhood $N$ of $z_0$ such that $g(z)\ne 0~\forall~z\in N\cap$ domain of $g\implies$ $g(z)\ne 0~\forall~z\in N\cap$ domain of $g.$

$f,g$ are analytic at $z_0\implies f,g$ are differnetaible in a neighborhood $H$ of $z_0.$

So $g(z)\ne 0~\forall~z\in A=H\cap N,$ a neighborhood of $z_0.$

Consequently $f/g$ is differentiable in $A.$